# Add element in between two other elements

Tags: sapui5

I have an enity 'person', a person can have 1 or more positions.

First question, do I need to create a new entity 'position' and create an association with the person and use $expand when loading the entity person to get these positions? (I tried to add a table type to my entity's structure, but that doesn't seem to work.)

Second question, how can I use JS to create new sap.m.Label and sap.m.Text elements and place them in between a list of other labels and text elements that have already been defined in an XML view?

Answer (score 1):

Answer to your Second question:

To add elements in `SimpleForm` you can use [`insertContent`](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.layout.form.SimpleForm.html#insertContent) of [`sap.ui.layout.form.SimpleForm`](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.layout.form.SimpleForm.html) class.

With this method you can add elements to `content` aggregation of `SimpleForm`.

Note: `content` aggregation has 0-based index.

Consider if you want to add second pair of `Label` and `Text` in `SimpleForm`, you will specify index position as *2* and *3* respectively, because at *0* and *1* you are having `Label` and `Text` from your `XML` view.

Working [example](http://jsbin.com/zokuco/edit?html,js,output)

Comment: Is it possible with a SimpleForm? Edit: insertContent it is.

Comment: Error: "Element sap.m.Label#__label35,Element sap.m.Text#__text32" is not valid for aggregation "content" of Element sap.ui.layout.form.SimpleForm#__xmlview1--SimpleFormDisplay354